# ¿ Porque no funciona el botón de ocultar la barra de redes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, redes-sociales

me a ayudado @Flowen a ocultar la barra de redes de mi web con un botón que la oculta y vuelve a mostrarla.
El código que hizo, funciona perfectamente, pero poniéndolo en mi proyecto no hace su función, siendo el mismo código.
Dejo mi código a ver cual es error que estoy cometiendo, por mas vueltas que le doy no funciona.
Gracias.

```js
    function ocultar(){
            $(".lateral").hide();
            $("#mostrar").show();
        }
        function mostrar(){
            $(".lateral").show();
            $("#mostrar").hide();
        }
```

```css
#mostrar{
    display:none;
    }

*{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.social{
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    top:200px;
    z-index: 2000;
}

.social ul {
    list-style: none;
}

/*.social ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition:all 500ms; 
    -0-transition:all 500ms;
    transition: all 500ms
}*/

.social ul li a {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition:all 500ms ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
    transition: all 500ms ease; 
}

.social ul li  .icon-facebook {background: #3b5998 ;}
.social ul li  .icon-twitter {background:#00abf0 ;}
.social ul li  .icon-youtube {background:#F8030E   ;}
.social ul li  .icon-google {background: #d95232;}
.social ul li  .icon-envelop {background: #666666  ;}
.social ul li  .icon-blogger2 {background:#F88103 ;}
.social ul li  .icon-info {background: #88F34F;}

.social ul li a:hover{
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Social</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="redes.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="redes-fonts.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    
</head>
<body>

   <div class="social">
       <ul>
           <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100009248037432" class="icon-facebook"></a></li>
           <li><a href="https://twitter.com/laparramiguel" class="icon-twitter"></a></li>
           <li><a href="http://www." class="icon-youtube"></a></li>
           <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/109747958435546403812" class="icon-google"></a></li>
           <li><a href="mailto: miguelestabaenlaparra@gmail.com" class="icon-envelop"></a></li>
           <li><a href="https://paseandoporlanubedelared.blogspot.com.es/" class="icon-blogger2"></a></li>
           <li><a href="http://www." class="icon-info"></a></li>
           <li><a href="#" class="icon-info lateral" onclick="ocultar()"></a></li>
           <li><a href="#" class="icon-info" onclick="mostrar()" id="mostrar"></a></li>

       </ul>
      
   </div>

<script src="redes.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: El código javascript dónde lo tienes? En otro archivo? Cómo se llama?

Comment: Se llama redes, esta suelto en la misma carpeta que el resto, css, html...etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te falta añadir la clase `lateral` a los que quieres ocultar. No te está ocultando los iconos porque ninguno posee la clase llamada `lateral`.

```
           <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100009248037432" class="icon-facebook lateral"></a></li>
           <li><a href="https://twitter.com/laparramiguel" class="icon-twitter lateral"></a></li>
           <li><a href="http://www." class="icon-youtube lateral"></a></li>
           <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/109747958435546403812" class="icon-google lateral"></a></li>
           <li><a href="mailto: miguelestabaenlaparra@gmail.com" class="icon-envelop lateral"></a></li>
           <li><a href="https://paseandoporlanubedelared.blogspot.com.es/" class="icon-blogger2 lateral"></a></li>
           <li><a href="http://www." class="icon-info lateral"></a></li>
```

Comment: Si que la tengo, antes de cerrar el body...Aunque la cambie al head, no funciona

Comment: Edito la respuesta.

Comment: Vaya tela, toda la mañana con ello. Si hubiera copiado tu código directamente... Claro que de ese modo no hubiera aprendido a hacerlo como a sido el caso. Muchas gracias compañero, muchas gracias. En cuanto me de opción la pongo como respuesta, que ahora no me deja. Gracias.